# ubuntu remove file with full permissions

Tags: linux, file-permissions, ubuntu-13.04

I created a file in the `/tmp/` directory. The file is owned by `mysql` user and has full permissions, i.e.

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql  mysql    16 Sep 23 12:44 artists.csv
```

Now I want to delete it, but get *Operation not permitted* error:

```
shimon@T61p:~$ rm /tmp/artists.csv 
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/artists.csv’: Operation not permitted
```

I only can delete this file using `sudo`.
I want to know why I cannot delete file which has all permissions for that using my user.

Output of `getfacl artists.csv`:

```
shimon@T61p:/tmp$ getfacl artists.csv
# file: artists.csv
# owner: mysql
# group: mysql
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::rw-
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `getfacl artists.csv`?

Comment: @terdon here it is.

Comment: It should at least be possible to delete it as root!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling around I found the issue:
The `/tmp` folder has the **sticky bit** special permission:

```
drwxrwxrwt  11 root root 36864 Sep 23 14:12 tmp
```

Note the **t** at the end of permissions - this means that the **sticky bit** is set. When the sticky bit is set, *any user can create files, but only the owner of a file can delete it.*[labor-liber.org](http://labor-liber.org/en/gnu-linux/introduction/special_permissions)

From [Ubuntu Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions):

> Within a directory upon which the sticky bit is applied, users are prevented from deleting or renaming any files that they do not personally own.

Comment: Ah, we found the same google results :). Well done. Remember to accept this answer so the question can be marked as answered.